# VJET Java2Js with Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vjet

Is it currently possible to execute the [VJET Java2Js compiler](http://www.slideshare.net/earlyster/vjet-bringing-the-best-of-java-and-javascript-together) from Maven or it's strongly bonded to the Eclipse IDE plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not strongly bonded to Eclipse plugin and yes it is possible to make this run with a build system such as maven.

It can be run with a java main or ant plugin. There is currently no support for a maven plugin today. We can make this work better by adding these to maven repo rather than just a p2 repo. Something I was planning on doing.

Here is the location of the ant plugin code http://git.eclipse.org/c/vjet/org.eclipse.vjet.core.git/tree/runtime/org.eclipse.vjet.rt.active.javatojs/src/org/eclipse/vjet/dsf/javatojs/prebuild/J2JsBuildTask.java

Here is the location of the java main:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/vjet/org.eclipse.vjet.core.git/tree/runtime/org.eclipse.vjet.rt.active.javatojs/src/org/eclipse/vjet/dsf/javatojs/cli/Java2Vjo.java